# Analytical gem on Heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, analytical

Good morning. I am trying to use this gem:

https://github.com/jkrall/analytical

On Heroku. It runs dandy on my local environment, but on Heroku busts out with:

```
2012-10-31T13:52:28+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 4, col 5: `' (ArgumentError)
2012-10-31T13:52:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
2012-10-31T13:52:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/analytical-3.0.12/lib/analytical.rb:14:in `block in analytical'
2012-10-31T13:52:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/analytical-3.0.12/lib/analytical.rb:13:in `open'
2012-10-31T13:52:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/analytical-3.0.12/lib/analytical.rb:13:in `analytical'
2012-10-31T13:52:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/api_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

The line in "api_controller.rb" it is references is simply the "analytical" statement that initializes the gem in that controller, per the documentation.

Tried putting "analytical" in application_controller instead and it errored out too (in both dev and staging).

Totally stumped. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, the issue turned out to be a syntax error in my `config/analytical.yml` file. In development, I was able to put my Google Analytics ID in without quotes around it, but on Heroku it gave this error. So instead of this:

```
production:
  google:
    key: UA-XXXXXXXX-X
```

I did this:

```
production:
  google:
    key: "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
```

Also, possibly you need to make sure there's a trailing carriage return after that last line